# Flag manifold is manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, lie-groups

I'm looking for the easiest way to see/prove that [flag manifold](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlagManifold.html) is indeed a manifold.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Do you already know that is is a homogeneous space?

Comment: @MoisheCohen How it can be viewed as homogenous space? As transitive action of  orthogonal group (I cannot deduce what is the stabilizer in that case)?

Comment: No, the general linear group is the one acting transitively. Can you work out the stabilizer of the standard flag $span(e_1)\subset span(e_1,e_2) \subset span(e_1,e_2,e_3) ...$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one systematic way to proceed is to observe that the general linear group $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ acts transitively on the set of complete flags in $\mathbf{R}^n$, and the stabilizer of the most obvious flag is the closed subgroup $B$ consisting of invertible upper triangular matrices. Thus there is a bijection (of sets) between $G/B$ and the set of complete flags.

Now it is a general fact that for a Lie group $G$ and a closed subgroup $B$, the quotient $G/B$ carries a unique manifold structure such that the projection is a $C^\infty$ map admitting local smooth sections (see e.g. Theorem 3.58 of Warner's book *Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups*). Thus while you might wonder if there are other manifold structures on the set of complete flags, there is a unique one that is compatible with the action of the general linear group in the sense just mentioned.